# Closure and Decorator

Tags: closures, python-decorators

I just discovered that decorator is one way of nesting functions and I came across this peculiar case with a concept called "closure". It basically means the nested function has access to the outter scope of an enclosing function. This looks intuitive enough till I found this piece of code as follows,

```
def decorator_with_arguments(function):
   "this decorator actually takes a real function as input"
    def wrapper_accepting_arguments(arg1,arg2):
        print("My arguments are: {0},{1}".format(arg1,arg2))
        function(arg1,arg2)
    return wrapper_accepting_arguments

@decorator_with_arguments
def cities(city_one,city_two):
    print("Cities I love are {0} and {1}".format(city_one,city_two))
cities("Beijing","Chicago")
```

The output would be as follows,

```
My arguments are: Bejing,Chicago
Cities I love are Bejing and Chicago
```

I have two questions regarding this piece of code.
First of all, isn't it amazing that the function `wrapper_accepting_arguments` understands that the arg1 and arg2 come from the function and print them off in a certain way before it has access to the `function(arg1,arg2)`? Does Python interpreter not read line by line? I understand when you apply multiple decorators to a function, say you have two @ along with a function, then the @ at the bottom gets excuted first. But within the body of a function, why it is read backwards?

The second question is that, if you delete the line of `function(arg1,arg2)` (as I tried to understand what it does), the output would be as follows,

```
My arguments are: Beijing,Chicago
```

as if you had never called the function of "cities" defined at the bottom. why is that?

This along with recursion works in a miraculous way. It's certainly not linear or from top down.

Thank you very much! Any pointer would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment this code

```
@decorator_with_arguments
def cities(city_one,city_two):
    print("Cities I love are {0} and {1}".format(city_one,city_two))
```

gets imported, the function `decorator_with_arguments` is called with the function `cities` as parameter. This will immediately return your inner function `wrapper_accepting_arguments`, which will effectively replace the definition of `def cities`.

So when you then call `cities("Beijing","Chicago")`, it is actually calling that inner function `wrapper_accepting_arguments` with the arguments `"Beijing","Chicago"`. This will cause `My arguments are: Beijing,Chicago` to be outputted followed by a call to the original definition of the `cities` (which was saved in the closure) resulting in `Cities I love are Beijing and Chicago` being printed.

Comment: I just came to understand the complexity of this issue arises when the function that a decorator decorates has agruments. The general approach is use *args an *kwargs, so that the decorators will understand and adapt to whatever and however many arguement the inside function have. Thank you for your info!